# Dendrogram plot remove tree labels at end of the branches

Tags: plot, label, dendrogram, dendextend

Using the example located here https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/hierarchical-clustering-R and the data located https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/seeds# i am trying to remove the labels at the bottom of the dendrogram when using the color_branches

when `plot(hclust_avg, labels=FALSE)` it works but not later when using color_branches. is there a way to remove them?

```
`set.seed(786)
seeds_df <- read.csv("seeds_dataset.txt",sep = '\t',header = FALSE)
feature_name <- c('area','perimeter','compactness','length.of.kernel','width.of.kernal','asymmetry.coefficient','length.of.kernel.groove','type.of.seed')
colnames(seeds_df) <- feature_name
seeds_df<- seeds_df[complete.cases(seeds_df), ]
seeds_label <- seeds_df$type.of.seed
seeds_df$type.of.seed <- NULL
seeds_df_sc <- as.data.frame(scale(seeds_df))
dist_mat <- dist(seeds_df_sc, method = 'euclidean')
hclust_avg <- hclust(dist_mat, method = 'average')
cut_avg <- cutree(hclust_avg, k = 3)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dendextend))
avg_dend_obj <- as.dendrogram(hclust_avg)
avg_col_dend <- color_branches(avg_dend_obj, h = 3)
plot(avg_col_dend)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out by colouring the the labels white to the background

`avg_dend_obj <- as.dendrogram(hclust_avg)
labels_colors(avg_dend_obj) <- "white"
plot(avg_dend_obj)`
 [image]